# RUnning shell script through sqlplus

Tags: python, oracle, shell, sqlplus

I am logged in as oracle in a prod env and I have a requirement to run SHELL scripts on remote hosts while I am in SQLPLUS. I am trying to do this via python. Is there any way to do it?

I am able to run SQL scripts or sql commands from sqlplus like the following :-

```
session = Popen(['sqlplus','-S','abc/abc@'+str(hostname)+':1000/'+str(dbname)+''], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    session.stdin.write('SPOOL '+str(op_file)+' \n'
                        ' '+str(data)+ '\n');

    session.stdin.write(' ; \n')
    session.stdin.write('exit \n')
    session.stdin.flush()
    stdout, stderr = session.communicate()
```

But when I want to run a shell script is there any way of doing it through sqlplus itself, coz the other way of logging in via ssh and sudoing in as oracle is not possible

I think this is one of the ways of doing it using PLSQL:-

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_execute_shell_script_plsql_procedure.htm

But am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

SQL*Plus is a client application.  It can spawn processes on the client machine which would run shell scripts on the client.  It cannot spawn processes on the database server.

As you've linked to, you can use the `dbms_scheduler` package on the database server to spawn processes on the server that would run batch files.  You can do something similar with a Java stored procedure since that also runs on the server.  `dbms_scheduler` also has the ability to [run jobs on remote servers](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/scheduler-enhancements-11gr1.php) if the appropriate scheduler agents are installed but this seems unlikely to be particularly helpful in the vast majority of situations.

Comment: What about doing it through pl/sql code block like using os_command.exec()   would it still run the command on the local?

Comment: @user3638694 - I'm not sure what you mean by "os_command.exec()".  Are you saying that you have a package in your database `os_command` with a procedure `exec`?  It's possible that someone wrote that.  If so, I'd guess that the `exec` procedure was calling a Java stored procedure that executed operating system commands along the lines of what I suggested in my answer.  If that's what you have, then the Java stored procedure would be spawning the processes on the database server.

Comment: But would this java procedure spawn process on the local database server or the remote database server that I connected to using   'sqlplus','-S','abc/abc@'+hostname+':1000/'+dbname

Comment: @user3638694 - The Java stored procedure would spawn the process on whichever database server the Java stored procedure was installed in.  If the Java stored procedure is installed on the remote database server, it would start a process on the remote database server.  If the Java stored procedure is installed on the local database server, it would start a process on the local database server.  The machine running SQL*Plus is the client machine whether it happens to have a database server installed or not.